# mdadm RAID5 3*3TB, 1 Drive with data

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

I have one disk (`sdd`) on which I currently have stored my data. I now have got two new 3TB disks (`sdb&sdc`) and want to create a RAID5 array over all three disks.

- `sdb`: gpt table, empty partition sdb1
- `sdc`: gpt table, empty partition sdc1
- `sdd`: gpt table, btrfs-partition sdd1 with my data

My plan looks like this:

- Create RAID5 array `md0` over `sdb1` and `sdc1`
- Create a btrfs filesystem on it.
- Copy the data from `sdd1` to `md0`
- Re-partition(=wipe) `sdd`
- Grow the array onto `sdd1`

---

I currently am stuck at creating the 2-disk RAID5 array. I built the array

```
# mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: size set to 2900832256K
mdadm: automatically enabling write-intent bitmap on large array
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

and `/proc/mdstat` shows that it's doing the initial sync:
I have one disk (`sdd`) on which I currently have stored my data. I now have got two new 3TB disks (`sdb&sdc`) and want to create a RAID5 array over all three disks.

- `sdb`: gpt table, empty partition sdb1
- `sdc`: gpt table, empty partition sdc1
- `sdd`: gpt table, btrfs-partition sdd1 with my data

My plan looks like this:

- Create RAID5 array `md0` over `sdb1` and `sdc1`
- Create a btrfs filesystem on it.
- Copy the data from `sdd1` to `md0`
- Re-partition(=wipe) `sdd`
- Grow the array onto `sdd1`

---

I currently am stuck at creating the 2-disk RAID5 array. I built the array

```
# mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: layout defaults to left-symmetric
mdadm: chunk size defaults to 512K
mdadm: size set to 2900832256K
mdadm: automatically enabling write-intent bitmap on large array
mdadm: Defaulting to version 1.2 metadata
mdadm: array /dev/md0 started.
```

and `/proc/mdstat` shows that it's doing the initial sync:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]
        md0 : active raid5 sdb1[2] sdc1[0]
          2900832256 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [2/1] [U_]
          [>....................]  recovery =  0.6% (19693440/2900832256) finish=308.8min speed=155487K/sec
          bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

    unused devices: <none>
```

top shows, that during this time, md(adm) uses ~35% CPU:

```
  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND
  989 root      20   0       0      0      0 S  29.1  0.0   0:17.69 md0_raid5
  994 root      20   0       0      0      0 D   6.6  0.0   0:03.54 md0_resync
```

So far so good. This should take ~6 hours. On my first try I had to reboot my server and thus stop the array after ~5h an the second time my `sdb` drive mysteriously disappeared, so I also had to restart the system.

The array started itself automatically, but the progress bar is gone:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10]      
md127 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdb1[2] sdc1[0]
      2900832256 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

and `top` reports no CPU-use.

So I tried stopping and assembling it manually:

```
~# mdadm --stop /dev/md127
mdadm: stopped /dev/md127
~# mdadm --assemble --verbose /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2) and 1 rebuilding.
```

Although it says it's rebuilding, mdstat shows no sign of that:

```
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdc1[0] sdb1[2]
      2900832256 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

also top again shows no CPU use.

So I searched the web for a method to manually force a sync and found `--update=resync`, but trying this also doesn't yield a victory:

```
~# mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm: stopped /dev/md0
~# mdadm --assemble --verbose --force --run --update=resync /dev/md0 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/sdc1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/sdb1 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: Marking array /dev/md0 as 'clean'
mdadm: added /dev/sdb1 to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: added /dev/sdc1 to /dev/md0 as 0
mdadm: /dev/md0 has been started with 1 drive (out of 2) and 1 rebuilding.
root@server:~# cat /proc/mdstat 
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid10] 
md0 : active (auto-read-only) raid5 sdc1[0] sdb1[2]
      2900832256 blocks super 1.2 level 5, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [2/1] [U_]
      bitmap: 0/22 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

unused devices: <none>
```

(still no CPU-use)

---

After two days of trying to fix it myself I would be very thankful for any help or advice

Comment: "I had to reboot my server and thus stop the array after ~5h an the second time my sdb drive mysteriously disappeared" -- well, that sounds like it could include just about anything, so I'd probably go with just redoing the whole thing from start. FWIW, if you're aiming for a three-drive array in the end, but need one to hold the data temporarily, I'd create the array with three drives from the start (`-n 3`) and just list one of them as `missing`. You can add the missing drive later on.

Comment: @ilkkachu My problem is just that I have no idea how to continue the sync process. `-n 3` doesn't work with just two drives

Comment: strongly recommend you don't do this.  btrfs still doesn't have a reliable raid5/6 capability, and btrfs on top of mdadm raid5 is no safer.   recommend ZFS instead (most distros have it packaged now, including dkms packages for the kernel module).  You can create a zpool with a missing vdev by creating a sparse file of the appropriate size using `truncate -s`, then `zpool create ....`, and then `zpool offline` the sparse file.  `zfs create` a fs on the pool, `rsync` your `sdd` data to it, unmount the `sdd` filesystem then `zpool replace` the sparse file with `sdd`.

Comment: @cas I've never had problems with btrfs, and since ZFS is too demanding for my server (4GB RAM), I think md(adm) is the most secure and reliable solution for me.

Comment: It's your data, you can trust it to whatever you want, but IMO you should thoroughly research the risks of btrfs raid5/6 first (the btrfs devs warn that it's only for testing), and research the various alternatives too.  BTW, just as with zfs, if you don't give individual drives/block-devs to the fs but instead layer btrfs on top of either hardware or software RAID, you lose the most important benefit of using the fs, error correction.

Comment: IMO your best option is to just add the two new drives to the btrfs pool and rebalance the data (see `man btrfs-balance`) across all 3 drives.  You'll end up with the same capacity as you would with raid-5 (6TB), without the risk of using experimental features and without losing btrfs's EC capability.   BTW, a year ago, I would have said "RAM is cheap, buy some more" but RAM prices have doubled or even tripled in the last year....even so, if your server has spare RAM slots I'd still recommend upgrading to 8GB or more.

Comment: rebalancing is the one feature that btrfs has which zfs doesn't - and it's a great feature.   (zfs has a lot more features wich btrfs doesn't have, and they're more important to me than rebalancing so I use zfs....still I wish zfs had it)

Comment: @cas I'm NOT using btrfs' raid feature at all, btrfs is only the filesystem ontop of my mdadm raid.

Comment: Then why are you even using btrfs?  if you want easily expandable storage, you've got three main options: 1. mdadm and/or LVM and a file system like ext4 or xfs; 2. btrfs; 3. zfs.  Do **not** use mdadm (or HW RAID) with either btrfs or zfs - it's worse than pointless, it's actively dangerous.   If you want error detection and correction, transparent compression, lightweight snapshots, subvolume capability, and more then your options are btrfs or zfs.   Like I said earlier (but with more emphasis this time):   You **really** need to do more research.

Comment: for example, you are messing around with mdadm when you **do not need to**.  You already have a btrfs filesystem on sdd1, and you've already partitioned your two new drives (sdb and sdc).  all you need to do is add sdb1 and sdc1 to your existing btrfs filesystem.   optional (but recommended for performance and safety), use `btrfs balance` to redistribute the existing files over all three drives that are now in the btrfs pool.  This will give you **better than RAID-5**.  the same storage capacity with a lot more features like compression and snapshots and subvolumes.

Comment: I already explained my dicision: 1.I have 4GB RAM => +ZFS+

Comment: 1.I have 4GB RAM => no ZFS 2. I want reliability => RAID => mdadm (since LVM uses mdadm itself, but is less mature, and as you said yourself, btrfs' RAID5 is very unstable) 3. I have/want my data on a CoW-capable FS => btrfs. I don't understand why you think the mdadm-btrfs combination would be any different than any other FS on an mdadm RAID.

Comment: if you understood why then perhaps you wouldn't need to be asking for and then ignoring the advice of those with more experience.  I repeat "You really need to do more research".  You are making poor decisions because you have not done enough research and because you dismiss the advice you asked for from those who have actually done the research and have the experience you lack.  Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

Since there's nothing on the raid array, the easy option is to just wipe everything and start over:

- `mdadm /dev/md127 --fail /dev/sdb1; mdadm /dev/md127 --fail /dev/sdc1; mdadm /dev/md127 --remove failed`
- `wipefs -a /dev/sdb1; wipefs -a /dev/sdc1`

Incidentally, I recommend creating a degraded RAID 5 array and then adding the third disk to it.  A rebuild is usually faster than a reshape, though there's an increased chance of data loss if a disk fails during the rebuild (you do have a backup, don't you?)

- `mdadm --create --verbose /dev/md0 --level=5 --raid-devices=3 /dev/sdc1 /dev/sdb1 missing`
- Create the new filesystem
- Copy the data
- `wipefs -a /dev/sdd1`
- `mdadm /dev/md0 --add /dev/sdd1`